# getBackgroundThrottling() or equivalent on Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, throttling

There's an (apparently undocumented) function of [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)s - `setBackgroundThrottling()`

Is there some way to check whether a window is set to throttle in the background though? I can't find either a property or a getter for that.

The reason I'm looking is to dynamically change the `backgroundThrottling` - but I need to determine the original value of `backgroundThrottling` to reset it when I'm done.

---

This is useful in a situation where you want to dynamically set the value back to its current value, after toggling it off.

I have a set of shared functions that are used across windows *with varying initial `backgroundThrottling` values*, but there's a place where I'd like to dynamically toggle it off, let a timer run, and then turn it back on. It would simplify (and speed up) the code quite a bit.

The issue is the timer doesn't run on time when throttled.

The alternative is to run the timer on the `main` process and communicate with the window using IPC. That means like 30 lines of code across at least two files, and enduring an extremely brief IPC delay. If I could determine whether the window was throttled from the window itself, it would take 4 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not aware of a getter. `backgroundThrottling` is on by default (as per docs). Is there any situation in which you suspect it holds a different value than the one you set?

Comment: @snwflk I updated my issue with a response to your question for formatting's sake

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/21036 and the setter is documented for `webContents` at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssetbackgroundthrottlingallowed